# Losing data from viewbag/tempdata after multiple post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've got problem with passing value. I am beginner in MVC, I read about `ViewBag`, `TempData` and I know it shouldn't work but I don't know how to make it work otherway. My problem:

Got 2 models : `Animal` and `Visit`

in my AnimalView I got list of all animals and I got this ActionLink:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add Visit", "Create", "Visit", new { id = item.AnimalID }, null)
```

it goes to Create GET method with id passed, I get a view to create visit I can submit it and everything is fine but..

for example if I don't set time for visit, model will not update and when method goes back to `Create` `Visit` View I don't have `AnimalID` already... can some1 tell me how to keep this value when post fails?

public ActionResult Create(int id)
        {
            Animal animal = db.Animals.Find(id);
            if (animal == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

```
       TempData["AnimalID"] = id;
        return View();

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "VisitID,AnimalID,DoctorID,VisitDate,VisitHour,Price,Recognition,Medicines,VisitDescription")] Visit visit)
    {



        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            visit.DoctorID = (int)Session["Doctors"];

            db.Visits.Add(visit);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(visit);
    }
```

Comment: Show us your create Visit action and view code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewBag and TempData only retain their information for one request. If the modelstate is not valid, you must re-set the ViewBag and TempData values.

Comment: ok i have tried that before and didn't work for me... but probably i just made some other stupid mistake that time. Now i added  TempData["AnimalID"] = visit.AnimalID; in my post method and its working, thanks !