# Redirect from controller to another view of another controller

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, list, razor

I have two controllers `Home` and `BookReservation` , i am trying to redirect from `BookReservation` controller to view of `Home` controller without redirect to index of home controller `if possible` .

this is my action on `BookReservation` controller :

`Validate_rules` function return `List<string[]>` and store them in `tempdata`

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Validate_Data(ReservationDetails reservation_details)
    {
        TempData["verification_errors"] = Validate_rules(reservation_details);//this function return List<string[]>  

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

and here the view index.cshtml of `home` i get the temp data and display the elements of it:

```
 @{
                    List<string[]> validate_rules = new List<string[]>();
                    if (TempData["verification_errors"] != null)
                    {
                        validate_rules = (List<string[]>)TempData["verification_errors"];

                    }
                }                   

                @foreach (var item in validate_rules)
                {                        
                    <label >@item[0].ToString() @item[2].ToString()</label>
                }
```

> the problem is i can not display the `validate_rules` elements inside view label i don't know where the problem from when i redirect the temp-data from `BookReservation` controller or what ?

this is home controller :

```
  [HttpGet] 
    [ActionName("Index")]
    [HandleError]
    public ActionResult Index_Get(string submit)
    {
        bool ParamsChanged = mySessionObject.Parameters.LoadQueryParameters(Request);

        if (ParamsChanged)
            return RedirectToAction("Index", mySessionObject.Parameters.GetQueryParameters());

        LoadHotelDetails();           
        GetHotelAvailability();

        ViewBag.data = TempData["verification_errors"];

        return View("Index",myViewModel);
    }
```

any advice ?

Comment: I recommend using `Session["verification_errors"]` instead. `TempData` stores in first & subsequent responses, when returning view on second controller possibly `TempData` values are already lost.

Answer (score 1):

change this   **return RedirectToAction("Index");**
to  **return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");** in Book Reservation controller

Book Reservation Controller
 -

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Validate_Data(ReservationDetails reservation_details)
{
    TempData["verification_errors"] = Validate_rules(reservation_details);//this function return List<string[]>

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

-- Home Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
      ViewBag.data= TempData["verification_errors"];
}
```

-- View

```
if (ViewBag.data!= null)
  {
    var list = ViewBag.data;
    foreach (var item in list)
     {                        
       <label >@item[0].ToString() @item[2].ToString()</label>
     }
  }
```

Comment: i still have same problem

Comment: hello hashim now try above approach may be it will work for you

Comment: i think the problem with `[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Validate_Data(ReservationDetails reservation_details)
{
    TempData["verification_errors"] = Validate_rules(reservation_details);//this function return List<string[]>

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}`

Comment: redirect to home view controller

Comment: to which controller action you want to redirect?

Comment: if possible i want send this tempdata to home view direct from Book Reservation Controller

Comment: my problem is the data of tempdata elements not display in the broweser after foreach

Comment: are you getting data in ViewBag.data(HomeController)?

Comment: then i think on view also you are getting then where is issue exactly? Can u please mention Home Controller and its view code. which u tried

Comment: what about home controller did you see it ?

Comment: you are getting data into home controller's viewbag then definitely u able to access it on view also and if u haven't changed tempdata to viewbag on view please change it and check

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is a composite one and it requires some decomposition:

1. A controller redirects to an action, so it definitely should be:

   ```
   return RedirectToAction ("YourAnotherAction", "YourAnotherController");
   ```

I cannot find the action of the `Home Controller` you are trying to redirect to. You want to avoid `Index` action of your `Home Controller`, but do not define the exact action you want to view.

2. Try to send some other data and check if all your routs are OK. Just check if you are examining the same area, project etc.
3. Just check if `TempData` is empty.

At last, Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani provided a good suggestion, check it. What's the problem that still persists? He proposes to redirect  to some other action - try it.
Hope that helps.

Comment: If you don't like the changes I've made to improve your answer by rejecting them, do not post them as your own, because this is called _plagiarism_. Furthermore, it is probably a good idea to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as it shows how Stack Overflow differs from a message board and why your addition is better suited as an upvote of the Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani's answer.

Comment: @scopchanov, didn't get your idea about the changes and plagiarism. I did not reject any changes. Sorry, if I posted some of your changes as my own (you mean numeration, I suppose?). Also, I still cannot upvote any answers, and the answer I propose seem to be broader. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I mean that my whole edit is there with the formatting and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell which view to load by using its path:

```
public ActionResult BookReservation()
{
     return View("Home/Index");
}
```

You can even do something like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction()
{
      if(SomeValue)
      return View();
      else 
      return View("Errors/AccessDenied");
}
```

Comment: i still have same problem

Answer (score 0):

`TempData` only retains information for two subsequent requests & often used for passing data between controllers (redirect). You can use `ViewBag` to pass the values into view:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Validate_Data(ReservationDetails reservation_details)
{
    TempData["verification_errors"] = Validate_rules(reservation_details);//this function return List<string[]>  

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
    var verification_errors = TempData["verification_errors"];
    ViewBag.Errors = verification_errors;

    // do something

    return View();
}
```

**View**

```
@{
     List<string[]> validate_rules = new List<string[]>();
     if (ViewBag.Errors != null)
     {
         validate_rules = (List<string[]>)ViewBag.Errors;
     }
}                   

@foreach (var item in validate_rules)
{                        
     <label>@item[0].ToString() @item[2].ToString()</label>
}
```

Or simply use `TempData.Keep` to keep the contents before returning view:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    TempData.Keep("verification_errors");

    // do something

    return View();
}
```

References:

[TempData value not persisting if used in view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487150/tempdata-value-not-persisting-if-used-in-view)

[Losing data from viewbag/tempdata after multiple post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679790/losing-data-from-viewbag-tempdata-after-multiple-post)

Comment: What's your problem then? Is that `TempData` still empty or other issues happened there? I think `TempData.Keep` can sustain the stored data when returning view.

Comment: tempdata not empty my problem is i can not display the items of list in the browser the list has all elements